# How do i handle a system("pause") when interacting with an command line programm using subprocess.popen

Tags: python, c++, subprocess, popen

I am trying to interact with a c++ program using python.

Imagine the c++ program looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::cout << "something" <<std::endl;
    std::cout << "something else\n";
    system("pause");
    std::cout << "result\n";
    std::cout << "something" <<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I want my python script to execute the c++ program and listen to its output until it gets the result. My current solution looks like this:

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen("testc.exe",stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
while True:
    line = proc.stdout.readline().decode('utf-8')
    print(line)
    if "result" in line:
        print("success!")
        proc.terminate()
        break
```

This works as long as there is no system("pause") in the c++ code. However, with the system("pause") call the python script hangs on read line.

How can I handle this when I can't change the source code of the c++ program? I don't want to use communicate() because then I can't react to each line in real time (and f.e. send some input to the c++ program)

Comment: You have to change the C++ source code and remove the `system()` call. There is no other option.